# Web Api 2 Method Issues on Deployed Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, iis-8

I am using MVC 6 RC 1 and IIS on my deployed server, and for some reason web methods that use parameters are returning a 404 ONLY on my deployed server.

Using postman with the following url:

http://*DEPLOYEDSERVERIP*/api/Util/ReleaseEquipment/5

Status 404 NOT FOUND

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →0
Date →Thu, 15 Sep 2016 18:29:16 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

Using postman with the following url:

Status 200 OK

http://localhost:3000/api/Util/ReleaseEquipment/5

```
connection →close
content-type →text/html; charset=utf-8
date →Thu, 15 Sep 2016 18:33:35 GMT
transfer-encoding →chunked
x-powered-by →ASP.NET
x-sourcefiles →=?UTF-8?B?QzpcQ0ZFVFNcQ0ZFVFNcc3JjXENGRVRTXHd3d3Jvb3RcYXBpXFV0aWxcUmVsZWFzZUVxdWlwbWVudFw1?=
```

However, if I run postman with the urls:
http://localhost:3000/api/Util/DeleteMeTest
http://*DEPLOYEDSERVERIP*/api/Util/DeleteMeTest

```
    [HttpGet("DeleteMeTest")]
    public String DeleteMeTest()
    {
        return "WORKS";
    }
```

BOTH of them work fine. So for some reason NO web api method on the server that requires parameters seems to work, and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I did further experiments and found the following:

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Random")]
public class RandomController : Controller
{

    private DBContext _context;

    public RandomController(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = DBContext ;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetZoneID/{zonename}")]
    public int GetZoneID(string zonename)
    {
        Zone zone = _context.Zones.Where(l => l.Name == zonename).First();

        return zone.ZoneId;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetZoneIDTEST/{zonename}")]
    public int GetZoneIDTEST(string zonename)
    {
        try
        {
            Zone zone = _context.Zones.Where(l => l.Name == zonename).First();
            return zone.ZoneId;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return -100;
        }


    }
```

Using postman, "http://199.131.110.4/api/Random/GetZoneIDTEST/sdgdsg" returns -100 with status 200 OK, but "http://199.131.110.4/api/Random/GetZoneID/sdgdsg" returns 404. So it seems uncaught exceptions ALSO are causing a 404 error.

Comment: Please post the method that gives you an error. 404 means it is a client side error. You have a parameter spelled incorrectly or an endpoint misconfigured. I bet this is an issue with the server allowing post/put/gets etc.

Comment: Made an edit. It seems methods that throw uncaught exceptions are also causing a 404 message(uncaught on the server side).